# Image Url doesn't get pushed to Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a register activity, which asks for user picture. When a picture is chosen from gallery, I am pushing the picture to firebase storage and then pushing the download url to firebase database. The picture is not pushed to firebase storage, but not to firebase database. Here is my code

```
cameraImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);

            }
        });


        mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        mChatPhotosStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("profile_pic");
```

And in my OnActivityResult code is as follows

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);



        if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
            filePath = data.getData();

            try {
                //getting image from gallery
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //uploading the image
                StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child("writedatabase");
                Log.i("Pritish", "onComplete: "+filePath);
                // Upload file to Firebase Storage
                photoRef.putFile(filePath)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                                User user = new User(null, downloadUrl.toString());
                                mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(user);

                            }
                        });


                //Setting image to ImageView
                cameraImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

`addOnSuccessListener` is never called. Can somebody please help me.

Comment: You say: "The picture is not pushed to firebase storage, but not to firebase database."  Where does the picture not been saved?

Comment: I am sorry.It doesn't get pushed to both. I am trying to push the image to storage and then its download url to database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove RegisterActivity.this from addOnSuccessListener parameter